# How to identify lists and libraries that were created by all user other than the default list available in a site

Tags: 2007, list, document-library

I have requirement where i have to display all lists and libraries that were created by the users in a sharepoint site. I could do this easily but the problem is i dont want to display the default lists and libraries that are created automatically when a site is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is probably to loop through all Lists and Libraries and compare the Created/Author properties of the SPList to the SPWeb. If the list is more than X minutes never than the site or by another user then it's probably user created. It's not fool proff, but especially if you have custom site definitions/templates then it's the only option.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what i thought and implemented. It helps for the time.